# How to get number type column data from MS Project file?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-project, mpxj

I am using MPXJ library to get data from MS Project file (.mpp).

ProjectReader reader = ProjectReaderUtility.getProjectReader(filename);
ProjectFile mpx = reader.read(filename);

Using ProjectFile object (mpx) I can get task, startdate, finishdate, duration, and some of other generally used column data. But I would not be able to get data of these type : Number1, Number2, ......; Date1, Date2,....; Flag1, Flag2,....etc.  Please help me how can get these field. I am using MPXJ 4.4.0

Regards,
Ashutosh Srivastava

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Task t;
Number number1 = t.getNumber(1);
Number number2 = t.getNumber(2);
Number number3 = t.getNumber(3);
// and so on
```